# External javascript file not working in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the property of a div from a javascript file but it's not working, it's working if I put it inside body but I want to work it from external js file for some project.

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Calendar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="javascript/cal.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="container">

      <div id="calendar-view">

      </div>

      <div id="events-view">

      </div>

    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

CSS file

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#calendar-view{
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
}

#events-view{
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

#container::after{
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

Javascript file

```
function startUp(){
  document.getElementById("calendar-view").style.display = "none";
}

startUp();
```

I'm trying to change the property of a div from a javascript file but it's not working, it's working if I put it inside body but I want to work it from external js file for some project.

Comment: I'd suggest to put it inside the eventListener window.onload to ensure your function execution after the element is created. and put your scripts down the body

Comment: Thanks for the help, i put the js file in header that's what the problem was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import your JS file at `<header>` your JS loads and then your body.

When you import your JS file after `<body>` your body loads and then your JS.

The first solution is to put your JS file after  the second one is to put the function call inside the [window onload event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload#examples)

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the `<script src="javascript/cal.js"></script>` at the end of the `</body>` tag.

You cannot get element from the DOM before the browser get it through the HTML.